# Sapient Apes - How to make them not Human?

Tags: evolution, humans, sapience

What if our common ancestor with chimpanzees still became intelligent and sapient, how could they end up very different from homo-sapiens, physically? Could they evolve in a different environment, or just take a slightly different niche in the one they already evolved in? What would we have to do in order to have something that looks and maybe behaves wildly different from us homo-sapiens?

Comment: VTC:NDC. We need to better understand your expectations. Are you asking about behvior? Motivations? Hairlessness? Your Q is trivially answered by all of the "Planet of the Apes" movies - but that might not be what you mean. Please explain both what you're looking for and what you are not looking for.

Comment: Need Defines Function: Evolution is a funny, fickle thing. Everything essential is reinforced, while anything non-essential dwindles with time. So you want an alternate evolution of an ape ton intelligence. WHY is that ape human-smart, instead of chimpanzee-smart?

Comment: With humans, we know that the drive to be bipedal tool users pushed up brain size. We know that you need to be smart to be a predator, especially when you are a weak, soft, vulnerable ape in a world of big, strong, powerful apex predators. I read once that human evolution was driven by the apparent attempt by nature to produce an ape apex predator. Simply being stronger was never going to get us there.

Comment: So the real question is, what do you want your intelligent ape to look like, and why do they need to be intelligent? Chimpanzees still exist. What they were doing still is still fulfilling a niche. Bonobos are very closely related, and nicer/less aggressive, but they still exist as they did, and don't need to be smarter.

Comment: You need to pick an end-point you want. Do you want a small, sweet, cooperative ape who raises crops and sings all day? Do you want a 600 lb. hunter who kills and eats the sweet apes for breakfast? You can do one, the other, or both. But you need to explain WHY they got that way, at each step of evolution, and explain how they were cooperative enough, and got enough protein for that big brain, and WHY they needed to have a big brain to achieve what they did.

Comment: I'm afraid the edits didn't solve my concerns. Why are you asking this question? What are your expectations? Why doesn't, "spiders co-evolved with humans and, miraculously, weren't wiped out by humans, so today we have two intelligent species, homo sapiens and aranea sapiens" not answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Humans are so varied from one culture to another, from one ethnicity to another that you really have to define the meaning of human.

Are neanderthals humans? Are all the species in the genus ''homo'' humans?
also how do you define species, since all the various definitions of species given by different scientists can be defeated and broken making species as arbitrary and non-sensical as races. Making it so that saying Homo Sapiens might be as non sensical and ignorant as saying Negroid and Mongoloid like the nazi used to define various human races.

So really, what is a human? If I'm neurodivergent enough, I still look like a human...naked hairless biped but my mind will be different from anything which can be recognized as human...

Are retarded, autistic, pedofiles, crazy people and other mentally divergent indivituals still human?

Are vegans human? Cannibals, are they human? Religions are common among human beings... but apparently Neanderthals where the first religious humanoids on this planet ... are religious people human?

If I'm born with a monkey tail or with my legs fused into a fish tail or with 6 fingers per hand, am I still human? People like that are born relativelly often, are they human?

If I get electrocuted and lose my ability to reproduce, am I human?

If my family inbred for generations and I'm born blue, like the blue fugates, am I human? Do you have to consider me a different race or species?

there's about a human being in therms of length of difference between Pygmeis and Dinka ? which one of them is the human? The abnormally tall one or the abnormaly short one?

Homo florisiensis was about the same height of pygmeis, does that mean that they are not human?

Are Italic people and German people the same species? In ancient time they thought of one another as different creatures... where they right? Genetically the difference is observable, so which one of them is human?

Comment: Grouping things into whatever categories is an easy solution when you want to adress masses and not individuals, but then you realize that groups blind the beholder from observing all the absurd individual differences. For all I care you could call a cat human, this type of grouping this and that is meaningless when the difference, genetic difference between two brothers might sometimes be enought to consider them different things. So who's to say my sister is the same species as me when species means nothing?

Comment: This sounds more like a rant, not an answer.